# Remove package tag from model image

Tags: image, copy, copy-paste, enterprise-architect

When selecting elements from a model and copying it to the clipboard as an image (CTRL+C) Enterprise Architect adds the package name as a label on the upper left. I now this can be suppressed by configuration but I don't find the option anymore... How can I disable this?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I use version 9.0 and achieved this by going to Tools > Options > Diagram > Diagram Frames and deselecting On Clipboard images.